# API Gateway Http Integration to Aspnet Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-api-gateway

Trying to set-up an API Gateway resource to an on premise REST API.  I have configured a simple resource weatherforecast, with an HTTP integration to my hosted web api.  This API is nothing more than the starter project for an aspnetcore web api with the WeatherForecast controller.

It is identical (I think) in every way to the demo Amazon [hosts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html#api-gateway-create-resource-and-methods).  When I go to test it, I get no response back.  If I configure the pets resource as in the tutorial, I get a response back.  Both are valid json.

I am not sure what else I need to do.  All I want is to surface a REST endpoint via API gateway and have it return the response from the app I have hosted on prem?

Comment: it's obviously some bug in your code so try yourself debugging first, if you can spot anything wrong and don't know how to fix, share the code here. BTW there is a framework to help build API gateway called `Ocelot`, you may want to have a look at it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am not sure it is obviously a bug in the code.  If I hit the endpoint directly I get a response.  This is literally the template aspnetcore web api project with zero modifications.

Comment: I feel confused now, you should add that in your question as well. Do make it clear about the difference between ***how you test it*** (in case of not working) and ***how you hit the endpoint directly*** (in case of working). Of course the bug I meant before is inside your API gateway implementation code (not in the services behind it)

Comment: It is in the question. "This API is nothing more than the starter project for an aspnetcore web api with the WeatherForecast controller."  By test it I mean the "test" feature in API gateway or even after it is deployed.  The body is empty if I attempt to get data from this integration via the api gateway.  If I go to my url directly - data comes back.

Comment: that's the API (services) which should be accessed (only) via your API Gateway. But the bug I meant lies in the API gateway, not in that `starter project`. I cannot even imagine how you create your API Gateway now, do you have a project for it? or you use some tool & configuration?

Comment: I literally followed the tutorial in the link step-for-step.  The ONLY difference being the URL and the name of the resource.  In my case I have a resource called "history" versus "pets".  The URL is NOT "http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/petstore/pets" as in the tutorial but rather "http://my-hosted-on-prem-app/endpoint"

Comment: well looks like you're using Amazon API Gateway, it may have more complicated problems (so that means you don't build the API gateway yourself in which case we create our own project, code everything and deploy it on our on-premises). I have less experience with AWS so not sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being with our infrastructure.  Putting the answer as something to check in the event someone else has the problem.

In our my case the app was sitting behind a firewall and load balancer.  Https termination is offloaded at the load balancer.

The API gateway threw an error when I set up the integration URL to use HTTPS.  So I tried initially to use HTTP.  Because the starter template Web API projects include

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

in the startup.cs, when the request would get to the app, a 302 re-direct to HTTPS would occur.  This is where one of the nuances of API Gateway come into play.  If you do not configure the API Gateway to also re-direct when a 302 is received, then the default status code is returned of 200.

We ended up fixing the SSL error.  The load balancer was missing the intermediate certificate.  It would not show an error in the browser, but tools like curl will throw an error.